# metrics induce the same topology

Tags: general-topology

So the theorem says: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Define a new metric $d':X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $d'(x,y):=$ min$\{d(x,y),1\}$. Then $d'$ is a metric and it induces the same topology on $X$ as $d$.

I've proved the first part of the theorem, that $d'$ is a metric on $X$. But I'm not exactly sure how to show that $d'$ induces the same topology as $d$.

I think it suffices to show that the basis of the topology induced by $d'$ is also a basis of the topology induced by $d$.

So let $B=\{B_d(x,\epsilon)\mid x\in X, \epsilon>0\}$ be the basis of the topology on $X$ induced by $d$.

Let $B'=\{B_d(x,\epsilon)\mid x\in X, 0<\epsilon\leq 1\}$ be the basis of the topology on $X$ induced by $d'$.

So my goal is to show that $B=B'$. Am I on the right track?

I guess it suffices to show that for each basic open set $B_d(x,\epsilon)\in B$, and for each $y\in X$, $y\in B_d(x,\epsilon) \iff y\in B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is for each $x\in X$ and each
$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\ep>0$ there is $\ep'>0$ with
$B_{d'}(x,\ep')\subseteq B_d(x,\ep)$ and there is $\ep''>0$ with
$B_{d}(x,\ep'')\subseteq B_{d'}(x,\ep)$.

Both really should be straightforward.